# i am trying to add interceptors to spring project,my prehandle method is not getting called

Tags: spring, interceptor

I want my prehandle method to be called.On debugging i see the control going inside ProductServiceInterceptor class but none of the methods inside are getting called

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class ProductServiceInterceptorAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
      registry.addInterceptor(new productServiceInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/home/*"));
   }
}


@Component
public class ProductServiceInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
   @Override
   public boolean preHandle(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
      
      return true;
   }
   @Override
   public void postHandle(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, 
      ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {}
   
   @Override
   public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
      Object handler, Exception exception) throws Exception {}
}
```

Comment: You registered it only for urls starting with `/home` so for any other url it will not be called. Are you using plain Spring or Spring Boot, if the latter remove the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation.

Comment: I am using plain spring, and i have tried it without using any specific url too, but the prehandle mehod is not getting executed

Comment: Then there must be something you are either doing wrong or you aren't using Spring MVC at all. With that this also means there is too little information to help formulate an answer as there are, apparently, parts missing.

Comment: Thank you it is working now,i added the mapping through XML configuration,my other doubt is if we want to in tercept only a particular url for example(http://localhost:8080/home/bussiness1).i want to include all the urls under home(/home/bussines2,/home/bussiness3) so how should my path pattern be for the interceptor

Comment: Both XML and Java should work the same. Not sure what you mean with pattern, the pattern is an ant-style pattern.

Comment: ok, thank you..